# What scala expects as a value when it's method accepts '?0' as argument type?

Tags: scala, vaadin

I want to pass a `String` type argument in a `setValue()` of **`vaadin`** with **`scala`**.

**Problem** : 
it shows like `def setValue(x$1: ?0): Unit`. it means it is expecting some `?0` type of arg.

i don't know how to handle this.
It will be nice if anyone can explain what is this type exactly, what kind of value it accepts and how can I pass `String` type arg to that method.

**Note** : `setValue(Object newValue)` works fine with **`java`**.

Here is the code snippet.

```
def getProcessTreeContainer(): HierarchicalContainer = {
var container = new HierarchicalContainer();
container.addContainerProperty("process", classOf[java.lang.String], null)

val tc = new TableCommon();
var process_menu_data_object_list = tc.getProcessTree();
val size = process_menu_data_object_list.size()

val obj = process_menu_data_object_list.iterator()
while (obj.hasNext()) {
  val key = obj.next().id
  val parent_key = obj.next().family_id
  var name = ""
  if (key == parent_key) {
    val l = obj.next().name

    //println(l.toString()+"...at step 1")
    println(("okiiess".asInstanceOf[String]))

    var child: Item = container.getItem(container.addItem(key))
    child.getItemProperty("process").setValue(l.asInstanceOf) 
    //  arg l.asInstanceOf(), what I am passing in setValue() method, throws NullPointerException.      
  } else {
    container.setParent(key, parent_key)
  }

   //println("okay...")
}
return container;
}
```

Comment: Can you post a snippet of your code?

Comment: What is the object type that you are trying to call its method `setValue`?

Comment: Here I added my code snippet. I don't know what kind of datatype is '?0'. I need to set String in container. but it simply don't allow me

Comment: it throws **ClassCastException** when I use setValue(l.asInstanceOf[String]). In java, setValue() expects argument of Object type, so String works  there.

Comment: What is TableCommon? Where does it come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?0` is not a datatype, it's Scala compiler telling you it doesn't know what the type is. The issue is that `child.getItemProperty("process")` [returns a raw type `Property` for some reason](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/data/Item.html#getItemProperty%28java.lang.Object%29), which aren't supported in Scala and shouldn't be used in Java either (it should return `Property<?>` instead). Cast it to `Property[String]`, since you know what its type actually is.

Comment: Thanxx@Alexey . Your suggestion worked. I have cast liked below and it solved that issue. `child.getItemProperty("caption").asInstanceOf[Property[String]].setValue(name)`

Comment: But does it means that `vaadin API` is not fully compatible with `Scala`? Because this thing is happening sometimes with different vaadin API methods in my code.

Comment: It isn't compatible if you need e.g. to write a class implementing `Item` in Scala. _Calling_ Vaadin API methods isn't a problem. The error here is correct and expected, because the compiler doesn't know what the type of property returned by `getItemProperty` is: if it's `Property<Integer>`, you shouldn't be able to call `setValue` with a `String`, right? The bug is that you should also get an equivalent error in Java unless you cast to `Property<String>`.